# Best way to SELECT aggregate values along with entities

Tags: typeorm

I have entity **One** that has one-to-many relation to entity **Two**. I want to select entity One and a COUNT of Two. I don't want all the data from Two - I'm getting lot of results and Two is large.

**What's the best way to do this with TypeORM?**

When I use QueryBuilder, I can get the COUNT with `getRawMany()`, but then all the entity columns are prefixed with alias, simple arrays are not converted etc. - inconvenient.

`getMany()` will omit the COUNT as it's not part of the entity structure. Can I somehow define a virtual column for the COUNT so it does get included?

Comment: Won't you be able to do so by joining *One* and *Two* and `.addSelect` the COUNT  by using subquery?

Comment: Yes, I can get the COUNT with addSelect, but only when I use `getRawMany`. I'm missing a nice way to convert those raw results to entity *with extra count field*.

Comment: Have you manage to solve this? I'm having a similar issue and I'd like to know if there is a solution or workaround for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I wrote my own primitive transformer... but possibly this could be a good start https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3513
Still curious about a good solution.